# why will setCustomView always leaves a little space on the left and the right?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

```
actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
ActionBar.LayoutParams params = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.head, null);
actionBar.setCustomView(view, params);
```

[like this,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3EZs.png)

I tried a lot of ways seached ,but failed..

Answer (score 0):

try this to remove the margin :

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
View customView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main_action_bar, null);
actionBar.setCustomView(customView);
Toolbar parent =(Toolbar) customView.getParent();
parent.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0,0);
```